# TypeError: Network request failed in android emulator and my IOS device

Tags: node.js, asp.net, react-native

I'm trying to write a new application in react native using asp.net core as my API but every time I am trying to fetch a response I get this error:

> Network request failed
>
> - node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:383:16 in callTimers
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4
>   in __callFunction
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6
>   in __guard$argument_0
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10
>   in __guard
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4
>   in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>
> - [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Here is my code:

```
function fetch2(){
    fetch('http://188.24.156.184:44386/weatherforecast')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
}
```

The request is working in browser, postman and emulator browser but not in app.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please don't attach your code as picture.  Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/tour